# I need to source my images. Is there any way to do that?

Tags: pdftex, wrapfigure

I have a plenty of figures in my thesis and I need to add internet sources to them at the end of my work. How can I make it happen?

EDIT: I do not have a list of figures. I use just large captions. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{{enigma/}} 

\begin{document}             

\maketitle

\section{Kryptografie}

\subsection{Historie}

Slovo kryptografie pochází z řeckého \textit{kryptos} (tzn. skrytý) a \textit{graphein} (tzn. písmo). 
Nejstarší šifry jsou připisovány Sumerům  (3500 B.C.) a Egypťanům (1900 B.C.).   \cite{dirac}
Vzhledem k tomu, že většina lidí neuměla číst, lze za šifrování považovat právě i sumerské klínové písmo nebo egyptské hieroglyfy.             

\section{Enigma}
\subsection{Teorie}

Motivací k tvorbě mechanického šifrovacího přístroje bylo počátkem 20. století mnoho.
Běžné, ručně šifrované texty byly příliš pomalé a s~rozvojem matematiky i neúčelné.
Tohle všechno ještě potvrdila 1. světová válka.

Mezi první takové pokusy patří například Hebernův stroj. 
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{hebern.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \centering
  \caption{Hebernův stroj}
\end{wrapfigure}

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{enigma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this list of sources different as the bibliography ?

Comment: Not different, but I want to separate it from the the rest of my sources (such as citations).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: Have you a list of figures ? Because it is possible to specify a "large" caption to go near the figure and a small one wich will go in the Table Of Figures. You could add the url in the small caption to have all of them in the list of figures.

Comment: Question edited, how do I work with the small caption and the Table of Figures?

Comment: I usually cite the source under the figure, e.g.

* Figure 1. Title [1]

* Figure 2. Title (image from [2])

Answer (score 3):

See, if the package `copyrightbox` can solve your problem. It is designed add image source to image:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{justification = centering}

    \usepackage{copyrightbox}% <---

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!h]
    \centering
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}{Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291234/i-need-to-source-my-images-is-there-any-way-to-do-that}
\caption{How to add image source}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a caption to the figure and another caption to the Table of Figures, you can use `\caption[Caption for Table of Figures]{Caption (may be longer) for the figure}`.

Frank

Comment: How can I add the source url of my image there? It completely messes up the table of figures.

Comment: Just use the command given above. Use a short description in squared brackets. This will end up in List of Figures. Skip a URL here. The complete caption incl. URLs or other sources/references should be included here.