# Putting reference in figure in LaTeX (llncs document class)

Tags: cross-referencing

I am stuck trying to put the reference in the figure in LaTeX.

My document class is :

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I inserted the figure in my document in this way:

```
\begin{figure} 

\centering 

\includegraphics[height=7cm]{ICS_toput}

\caption{Components of ICS} 

\label{fig:example}

\end{figure}
```

Now I need to add a reference (source) to this figure.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "source"? Like an additional piece of text that is not the `\caption`, but sources the original `ICS_toput` picture?

Comment: @Werner I took the idea of this picture from a different research paper. I need to cite that as a source in the figure. I am unable to achieve that.

Comment: Perhaps try [I need to source my images. Is there any way to do that?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291234/5764) Do you have restrictions in terms of packages you may use?

Comment: @Werner I am using the llncs document class. So anything that could fit with that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For image sources that are no wider than the image itself, you can use a simple `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imgsourcefont}{\normalfont\footnotesize\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image} \\
    \imgsourcefont Image source \ldots
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Components of ICS}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can define a global `\imgsourcefont` to provide consistency across these source setting. If your source is wider than the image, you can set the contents in a `p{<len>}` column, or something else altogether.

Alternative reference: [I need to source my images. Is there any way to do that?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291234/5764)